# Why are all my threads returned as main?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.5

This script turns ON and OFF 2 Phidgets relays (www.phidgets.com). I wanted to open and close the relays in separate threads. The script below runs but prints each thread as a Main Thread like this

```
    Waiting for attach....
    172760 attached!
    Phidget InterfaceKit 8/8/8 model
    MainThread Starting
    relay state is True
    MainThread Exiting
    MainThread Starting
    relay state is True
    MainThread Exiting
    MainThread Starting
    relay state is False
    MainThread Exiting
    MainThread Starting
    relay state is False
    MainThread Exiting
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Basic imports
from ctypes import *
import sys, random, time, decimal, threading


#Phidget specific imports
from Phidgets.PhidgetException import PhidgetErrorCodes, PhidgetException
from Phidgets.Devices.InterfaceKit import InterfaceKit

class fidget(object):
#Common base class for all phidgets

    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = InterfaceKit()

########################################        

    # open the interfacekit         
    def openIfkit(self):
        try:
            self.device.openPhidget()
            self.device.waitForAttach(10000)
            print("Waiting for attach....")
            print ("%d attached!" % (self.device.getSerialNum()))
            print ("%s model" % (self.device.getDeviceName()))
        except PhidgetException, e:
            print ("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.detail))     
            exit(1)

    # open the interfacekit         
    def closeIfkit(self):
        try:
            self.device.closePhidget()
        except PhidgetException, e:
            print ("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.detail))     
            exit(1)

    def relayOn(self, output):

        # Set digital output port 0 to be on
        print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Starting'
        self.device.setOutputState(output, 1)
        time.sleep(.1)
        print 'relay state is %s' %self.device.getOutputState(output)
        print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Exiting'

    def relayOff(self, output):
        print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Starting'
        self.device.setOutputState(output, 0)
        time.sleep(.1)
        print 'relay state is %s' %self.device.getOutputState(output)
        print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Exiting'

#"This would create first object of fidgit class"
x = fidget('ifkit')
x.openIfkit()


#t1 = threading.Thread( target=x.relayOn(0))
#t2 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOn(1))
#t3 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOff(0))
#t4 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOff(1))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOn, args=(0,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOff, args=(0,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOn, args=(1,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=x.relayOff, args=(1,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()

x.closeIfkit()
```

Comment: I got it to work by changing t1,-t4 as above, I am not sure if this is correct or not? Thanks again for those who answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a callable to `target=`, like so:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: x.relayOff(1))
```

at the moment, what you did is calling `x.relay*` on the main thread and passes its return value (i.e. `None`, because in python functions that doesn't return explicitly, returns `None`) to `target=`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `relayOn` and `relayOff` two times each in the main thread, and never in your child threads, which don't do anything at all. The `target` that you're giving to `threading.Thread` is the *return value* of `relayOn` or `relayOff`, which (since those functions don't return anything) is `None`, so the threads don't run anything.

One way to fix this would be to create a closure that does what you want:

```
t1 = threading.Thread( target=lambda: x.relayOn(0) )
```

etc.